# Can WSO2IS log SSO session data for measuring specific website usage activity?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to accomplish logging of session data in Identity Server for users who access websites/resources that are integrated with Identity Server SSO. Is there an easy way to do this? I saw the log4j.properties file in ../repository/conf, however it doesn't provide what I'm looking for. Let me know if anyone needs further clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a predefined Session Data Publisher (`DASSessionDataPublisherImpl`)[1] that is used by Identity Server Analytics to analyse session data. You can use that to retrieve data.

[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Prerequisites+to+Publish+Statistics#PrerequisitestoPublishStatistics-EnablinganalyticsforIdentityServer

Or else try WSO2 Identity Server Analytics.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Analytics

Comment: Thanks Jayanga. I'll give those a try.